# Model for sound generated by air flowing through pipe

Tags: acoustics, resonance, turbulence

I'm trying to write a program simulating the sound of an petrol car engine, just for fun.

As a part of this, I'm trying to model the sound of air escaping the combustion chamber through an open poppet valve.

I tried modeling the flow of air through a hole as an Aeolian sound (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolian_sound), but I think this is not a good model, since it predicts very high pitched sounds (in the multiple kilohertz range for a regular car engine at full load).

I'm thinking the exhaust sound of a car comes from several phenomena:

1: The direct pressure variation in the exhaust system when the valve opens and hot, high-pressure exhaust gas flows into the exhaust system.

2: Some kind of (pink?) noise from the chaotic, turbulent air flow.

3: Lots of resonances in the engine, car etc.

4: Acoustic resonance in the exhaust system, particularly at certain engine speeds.

(Then we have of course, intake sound, sound of gearbox, accessories, camshafts etc, but that's a later problem)

I think I have some idea to approximate #1, #3 and #4, but I'm stuck regarding #2.

What is the mechanism causing a white/pink-noise sound when air flows through a narrow opening? How could I model this?